# How to get description of folder in picture library show to thumbnails view on a page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

My picture library has folders and every folders has pictures, I want to show all pictures in folder and description of folder on a page

layout:

[pic] [pic] [pic] [pic] [pic]

[pic] [pic] [pic] [pic] [pic]

[pic] [pic] [pic] [pic] [pic]

--description of folder(description for all pictures)--

ps. idk what's version of my sharepoint(enterprise, I think), I can manage site,create web page,add webpart by this sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that by using JSLink, there are examples on msdn / technet and other blogs. For instance: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn745867.aspx

Comment: I can add app to show picture library but can show description for all pictures